# Выгрузка данных в excel  средствами php

Tags: php, excel

Вопрос такой! У меня есть данные, содержащиеся  в массиве! Мне нужно не просто все данные загрузить в excel, а есть у меня есть критерий (отделение)! и что бы у меня  по отделениям создавалась книга в файле! если не правильно объяснил! то смотрите рис.

[image]

Comment: или хотя бы скажите как создавать книгу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> и что бы у меня по отделениям создавалась книга в файле!

это не книги а [листы](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#.D0.A1.D1.82.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0_.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.B9_.D0.BA.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B3.D0.B8) (worksheets)

[**PHPExcel**](http://www.phpexcel.net/)

> PHPExcel is a library written in pure PHP and providing a set of classes that allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats, like Excel (BIFF) .xls, Excel 2007 (OfficeOpenXML) .xlsx, CSV, Libre/OpenOffice Calc .ods, Gnumeric, PDF, HTML, ... This project is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard and PHP.
>
> PHPEcel это библиотека, написанная на чистом PHP, и предоставляющая набор классов позволяющих вам осуществлять считывание и запись различных форматов электронных таблиц, таких как Excel (`*.xls`), Excel 2007 (`*.xlsx`), CSV, OpenOffice Calc (`*.ods`) и т.д. Проект создан на основе стандартов Microsoft [OpenXML](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)

- [Создание Excel-файлов с помощью PHPExcel](http://www.web-junior.net/sozdanie-excel-fajjlov-s-pomoshhyu-phpexcel/)
- [Редактирование Excel-файлов с помощью PHPExcel](http://drobot.in.ua/2012/02/excel-phpexcel.html)
- [PHPExcel Cheatsheet](http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/phpexcel-cheatsheet)

Comment: Самое нормальное решение. И да, кушает тоже нормально :)